# Can't open an Excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

Code:

```
import openpyxl as opxl
wb = opxl.load_workbook('Food.xlsx')
```

[Here is Food.xlsx in flder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYeWx.png), but nothing happened.

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Food.xlsx'
```

Also, when I use full path method, it returns yet another error.
Code:

```
import openlyxl as opxl 
wb = opxl.load_workbook(C:/Users/adminname/Desktop/Workplace/Folder/MiniFolder/FileName)
```

And I got a bad zip file error.

Comment: Depending on IDE preferences and your user setup, the default search path may be your home directory, and not necessarily the same directory where your source file is. You will have to be more specific in stating the file's location, i.e. './Food.xlsx' or the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options;

**1. Input the full path to your file;**

```
import openpyxl as opxl

wb = opxl.load_workbook('full_path/to_your/folder/Food.xlsx')
```

**2. Change your script's working directory;**

```
import os
import openpyxl as opxl

# change working directory
os.chdir('full_path/to_your/folder/')

# check the current working directory
print(os.getcwd())

# load your file by name 
wb = opxl.load_workbook('Food.xlsx')
```